# The mystery of the anonymous email

Tags: cipher, steganography

It is a bright Sunday afternoon. You are on a holiday, enjoying your cappuccino. Suddenly, you get a call from your boss at **NSA**. He tells you that a psycho-hacker has sent him and the whole staff a weirdo-looking image attachment sent using an anonymous email sending service. Hearing that, you quickly log into your email account and find this:

[image]

**Now, the question: Who sent this message?**

**EDIT 1:-** Someone changed the password of the Gmail Account an hour ago. So, instead of that hint. See the below hint:-

You spot down all hints and at last, you find an email and password. You login and find the following email in the inbox:-

> From:XXXXX
>
> To:mXXXpuXXX@gmail.com
>
> Subject: FINAL HINT
>
> > You are an inch away from solving this puzzle. You might want to  see
> >     the attached image.
> >
> > BTW I love mosaic tiles :)

Attached Image: [Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXdER.png)

> [image]

**EDIT 2:-** I have changed the case of the account password. Please don't change the password and hinder the experience of others, the account is blank and is of no use. You may need to use an Indian VPN/Proxy to login (Curse Google!).  If the password has been changed again, then use the above edit :)

Comment: I'm gonna assume "by **the** time..." and "**I** believe that **you** are one of...." the words the and you are left out on purpose? Also should it not be I will have died? and shouldn't i in that sentence be a capital I? would have indicates he hasn't died?

You have made a picture of it for a reason so i'm guessing you're a master in English and every thing i find odd with the text is deliberate?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Typo and I can't edit that image for a reason now ! BTW that's how hackers write, they don't give a fu## about grammer or thing.

Comment: :p haha, so he has died. and the left out words are not intended? Also i wish i had a program to which i could give an image and have it brute force the information out of it much like cryptocrack for ciphers. anyhow, lets get looking for that password ;)

Comment: "Also should it not be I will have died? " No, instead it should be I would be dead. Anyways, can't edit it now! @VincentAdvocaat Lets See :)

Comment: You're on the right track. Just keep going :)

Comment: Don't spoil it Vince! I'm still guessing passwords!

Comment: Removed it @Bob sorry

Comment: Lets see how much time it takes.. :)

Comment: I suck at this so don't hold your breath :P

Comment: Haha OK @VincentAdvocaat

Comment: It was sent by POOP.

Comment: @Voitcus Nah, I wouldn't have posted that simple..

Comment: I tried to hexdump the image file (you said you can't edit the image) and find "nullbyte" (ie. `00`), but there's many. Is it good way to follow?

Comment: Well, ok, I already know. I was so close...

Comment: I found the password (for the gmail) but it needs an access location.. Is this part of the puzzle?

Comment: No, maybe a problem with Gmail, tell me where you're from(country) so that I can see the problem @WorldSEnder

Comment: Germany (Frankfurt if you need a city)

Comment: **Everyone, please see the updated QUESTION**

Comment: @SharadGautam Do you have an acceptable answer here yet?  Bob's looks good.

Comment: @LeppyR64 I forgot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sender is going by the name of POOP and...

> IAMINCREDIBLE - masterpuzzler007@gmail.com  is his email address (not sure of his name yet)

The image contains a hidden message...

> ...which you can find by opening it with a text editor and looking at the end where there is a link to file hosting site that requires a password.

Once you have found that you need to know that...

> ...the password is `00`  hence the clue "nullbyte"

Then you get:

```
6d617374657270757a7a6c657230303740676d61696c2e636f6d

Hint:You may need a different point of view for the next one.

454c4249444552434e494d4149
```

This is...

> ... a hexadecimal string representation of the ascii values of `masterpuzzler007@gmail.com` and `ELBIDERCNIMAI` (I AM INCREDIBLE backwards)

Once you've found this...

> you can access the email account to get a picture similar to the one in the original message (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXdER.png) which has an anomaly in the top left corner. Some of the pixels looked smudged downward but they have actually been more significantly altered. The thin grey strip along the top of the image is not pure grey in the smudged section. Each of the 19 pixels is a different colour to the unsmudged portion of the strip. Presumably these pixels encode the name we are looking for.

The hexadecimal values of each pixel are:

> cec1b9 cfc3ba cdc1ba cfc1bb cec0bb ccc0b9 ccc0b9 cdc1bb cec0bb cfc1b9 ccc3b8 cfc0bb ccc1bb ccc1ba cec1bb cfc0b8 cfc0b9 cfc3bb cec3ba

If you are hoping to work this last bit out by hand good luck to you.
Credit to Quark and LeppyR64 who worked out the final step, which is:

> Enter the new image into http://mozaiq.org/decrypt with the password "00" to get the line "Yes, you've found me. My name is VGVjaFJheA==". This is Base64 encoded and translates to TechRax.

Comment: There is still a long way to go. I hope you like it so far :)

Comment: Am I supposed to mail that address? I'm not sure what else is left.

Comment: Professor Layton is dead? Or did I go off on a huge tangent

Comment: **Everyone, please see the updated QUESTION**

Comment: @SharadGautam Thanks, that helps me keep going :)

Comment: @Bob What's the progress?

Comment: @SharadGautam I've extracted a few bytes that could be a name but I haven't had any luck turning them into text. I almost expected someone else to have worked it out by now.

Comment: @Bob The email in the ***edit 1*** is your ultimate hint. Just wordplay :) and  a "rephic" and a "qiasom".

Comment: This website isn't necessarily general knowledge and wasn't obvious to me the first time I encountered it: see my edit to your answer

Comment: @LeppyR64 how did you know that site was the one used?

Comment: @Quark see Sharad's last comment on This answer.  Also the Mosaic tiles comment.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Ah I just realized "qiasom" is "mosaiq" backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to Bob and LeppyR64 who basically solved it, here's the last part:

> Enter the new image into http://mozaiq.org/decrypt with the password "00" to get the line "Yes, you've found me. My name is VGVjaFJheA==". This is Base64 encoded and translates to TechRax.

Comment: Excellent Work :)

Comment: Well done! I had never heard of that website so probably never would have solved this.